# NSCondition deadlock

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa

I'm working on an app which receives data from an HTTP connection and the data is processed by one or more threads as it comes in. I use an NSCondition to allow the reader threads to wait for incoming data and have the connection thread broadcast them when data is available but I keep getting deadlock and I can't see why. I'm either misunderstanding how NSCondition works or I've spent so long staring at it that I'm missing something else. Here's the code:

```
// lock = NSCondition ivar
// position = long long ivar
// writeDataToFile performs no locking but just writes the data to an NSHandle and logs in debug

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data {
    [condition lock];
    @try {
        [self writeDataToFile:data];
        position += [data length];
        hasMoreData = YES;
    } @finally {
        [condition broadcast];
        [condition unlock];
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response {

    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    int statusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
    requestSuccess = (statusCode == 200);

    [condition lock];
    [condition broadcast];
    [condition unlock];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error {
    [condition lock];
    hasMoreData = YES;
    [condition broadcast];
    [condition unlock];
}

- (void)waitForData {
    [condition lock];
    @try {
        while( !hasMoreData ) {
            [condition wait];
        }
    } @finally {
        hasMoreData = NO;
        [condition unlock];
    }
}
```

Now this generally works but occasionally I see the app hang and a sample shows one thread waiting on the condition, another waiting to acquire a lock in `waitForData` and the other waiting to acquire a lock in `connection:didReceiveData'.

My understanding is that the `[condition wait]` call atomically unlocks it's internal mutex and waits on the condition so multiple waiting threads should not prevent the `connection:didReceiveData:` thread from acquiring and broadcasting the condition.

What am I missing?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

Guess, use this method

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

and in this unlock the conditions. when you are not getting the response then `[condition unlock];`

this line is not calling. so these are locked and your app hangs so try to use this suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am unlocking the condition in the failure method (question updated to include the code). I didn't include it because in this case the connection is not failing as a thread is hanging in the connection:didReceiveData: selector.

Answer (score -1):

At the end of the day I think using locks is a convoluted solution. Using synchronous IO on the main thread is a big no-no, but doing it on a background thread is both ok, and **much** easier then handling the asynchronous requests.

So if you are on a background thread the whole mess with blocking the current thread to wait for the IO thread is just a pain in the ass. Replace with a `+[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:]` and be done with it.

Comment: Thanks for the information but I'm actually using an NSCondition, not an NSConditionLock - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCondition_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: My bad. I still believe that using any kind of lock is a last resort. `NSURLConnection` already have a perfectly good and super tested implementation for blocking IO; use that if you already are on a background thread. So I update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Unforuntately due to the complexity of the app, locking is indeed necessary as multiple threads could be reading from multiple locations within the file data during a download. The problem was actually down to a race condition when setting a boolean. I have implemented a "double lock" around the boolean and it is now working fine.